# SQL Server: GROUP BY datetime without ticks

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a query, that returns all entries, with unique `datetime` with ticks:

```
select t.date, count(*) as Count
    from table t
    group by t.date having count(*) = 1
```

I need a query that will return entries with unique `datetime` without ticks. To get `datetime` without ticks I'm using:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), t.date, 120), count(*) as Count
from table t
```

So I'm expecting to use query:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), t.date, 120), count(*) as Count
    from table t
    group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), t.date, 120) having count(*) = 1
```

But it throws an error:

> Column "table.date" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Do you have any idea what query should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine:

```
select convert(varchar(19), t.date, 120), count(*) as count
from table t
group by convert(varchar(19), t.date, 120) 
having count(*) = 1
order by convert(varchar(19), t.date, 120)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple possible `datetime` values in each group so instead of

```
ORDER BY t.date
```

you could use, for example

```
ORDER BY MIN(t.date)
```

to avoid this error.

Comment: Of course, `ORDER BY`! He didn't include the clause in the query and I missed the reference in the error message entirely. Absolutely agree, +1

Answer (score 1):

You have to ORDER BY an expression in the GROUP BY or an aggregation

```
ORDER BY
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), date, 120)
```

example:

```
SELECT
   ShorterDateTime, COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), date, 120) AS ShorterDateTime
    from table
    ) t
GROUP BY
   ShorterDateTime
HAVING
   COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
   ShorterDateTime
```